# How i can write fromEvent(window, 'scroll')unit test using sinon js, mocha & chai for the next method?

Tags: sinon-chai

addScroll(): void {

```
fromEvent(this.$size, 'scroll')
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.unSubs$))
  .subscribe({
    next: () => this.scroll = this.$size.pageYOffset > 5
  });
```

}